# grouping HTML elements in vuejs using v-for

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js

I am new in vue.
I want to display a HTML structure in vue.js based on API data.the HTML structure it's like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div><p>text1</p><img src="{{imgurl1}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text2</p><img src="{{imgurl2}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text3</p><img src="{{imgurl3}}" /></div>
</div>
<div class="row">
  <div><p>text4</p><img src="{{imgurl4}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text5</p><img src="{{imgurl5}}" /></div>
  <div><p>text6</p><img src="{{imgurl6}}" /></div>
</div>
```

each div with class row has 3 divs.
this is my vue code:

```
<div class="row">
  <div v-for="(client, index) in clients">
    <div><p>text4</p><img src="{{imgurl4}}" /></div>
    <div><p>text5</p><img src="{{imgurl5}}" /></div>
    <div><p>text6</p><img src="{{imgurl6}}" /></div>
    <div v-if="index % 3 === 0">
       </div>
       <div class="row">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but it doesn't display correct HTML structure
what I missed, how to grouping 3divs ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work...

```html
    <div v-if="index % 3 === 0">
       </div>
       <div class="row">
    </div>
```

is that unlike server side templating, which treats the content as strings, vue interprets that html as js, and you're passing un-terminated elements.

---

Nested loops is the easiest way to do this

here is an example (I'm using table instead of divs, to illustrate the point with less css, but the rest should be the same)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    imgs: ['img0', 'img1', 'img2', 'img3', 'img4', 'img5', 'img6', 'img7', 'img8', 'img9', 'img10'],
    numCols: 3,
  },
  computed: {
   numRows(){
    return Math.ceil(this.imgs.length / this.numCols)
   }
  }
})
```

```css
table {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.6.2/vue.js"></script>

<table id="app">
  <tr v-for="row in numRows+1">
    <td v-for="col in imgs.slice((row-1)*numCols, row * numCols)">
      <div>
        {{col}}
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

You may be able to skip the nested v-for if you want to provide three items manually.